# Building a circuit

Tags: digital-logic, circuit-analysis, integrated-circuit, logic-gates

We have a battery and using 4 switches and logic gates build the system where if any of the switches is closed light should be turned on.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Is this homework? Also, note that when you use the schematic button on the editor toolbar you can save an editable schematic into your post.

Comment: What do you expect the two resistors to do? Except flatten the battery in about two weeks...

Comment: I want the first one to reduce the voltage from 12V to 7.5V and send this voltage to the switches.

Comment: V2 would be the input to the switch, however I agree with @BrianDrummond, you probably want the voltage divider on the gate side of the switch, not the battery side. You may also want to think about using higher values for your resistors.

Comment: Yes, I want the voltage divider

Comment: Keep the divider, but you should have 4 of them (one for each switch) and connect 12V directly to the switches. Watch out though for the short to ground.

Comment: @rikovvv: Be careful with your edits. Your reversal of the switches makes my answer look a bit stupid as nobody will have a clue why I have a schematic of backwards switches. You could either leave the incorrect schematic and add the fixed one or add a comment. Don't worry about it this time though.

Comment: Homework detected. I assume that someone that will project the internal light system of a car needs not to ask in EE.SE. The OP could have at least tried.

Answer (score 5):

Just a hint for now:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEHR2J.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. (a) Won't work. (b) By reversing the switches it becomes simple.*

Now the next hint: why are you using OR gates? Old fashioned cars had interior lights that just worked when any of the switches connected the wire to ground (-) when a door was open. Can you figure out how they were wired?

Comment: I'm guessing he is using OR gates because this is homework and it is a logic exercise...

Comment: Yes, that's right

Comment: @rikovvv: Your question doesn't mention what type of logic you are using (TTL, CMOS, etc.) Can't you put that in your original question?

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frLXuD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

(This is just one way of doing this)

<strike>First, you shouldn't be using 3 position switches, there isn't a need in this case, the switches are either closed or open.</strike> I noticed that it is possible that the gate requires a logic high or a logic low to operate correctly, so instead of using a floating value and hoping it isn't a "high", you can use the 3 position switch to drive the OR gate low.

Assuming that these OR gates transfer input voltage directly to output voltage (a big assumption by the way, some gates, like those modeled in CircuitLab above, drop around 2.5V, which means that OR3 wouldn't have enough voltage to notice a high level), this should work without draining the battery while not in use. Because the load is low, you should be choosing resistor-divider's in the higher end range, possibly even 2-3 times what the diagram above shows, but I think that is outside the scope of the question at hand.

Just for completeness, all of this could be eliminated! :)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7kw6w.png)</sup>

Does pretty much exactly the same thing, assuming the lamp is a 12V lamp.

Comment: Ok, thank you, I've understood!
But why do we need resistors R6-R9?
Can we connect resistors R1-R5 directly with the logic gate?

Comment: The resistors act as a voltage divider, assuming the OR gates cannot handle more than 7.5 volts, this will divide the 12V into 7.5V. If you just had a resistor there, it would block the current, but you would still get the full 12V and burn out the gate.